# unable to call LogOff method in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have started a project using MVC6 and can't seem to route to the LogOff method.

The account controller looks like this:

```
     //
    // POST: /Account/LogOff
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LogOff()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation(4, "User logged out.");
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
    }
```

The calling navigation looks like this:

```
 @if (User.IsSignedIn())
{
    <div class="profile-picture">

        <div class="stats-label text-color">
            <span class="font-extra-bold font-uppercase">@User.GetUserName()</span>

            <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <small class="text-muted">Title <b class="caret"></b></small>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX m-t-xs">
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")">Log off</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I have applied a break point in the on the first line of the method in the controller however it never breaks on it and the browser just goes blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added custom routes to the routing table?

Comment: A link is a GET method - you have marked it `[HttpPost]` and also added `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` so it will never be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")">Log off</a></li>
```

Try replacing like this:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
                                    {
                                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
                                    }
```

Comment: Thanks that made the logoff work but I am new to this and I am not sure what you code is doing. I notice the style of the Log Off menu item is different than other menu items.

Comment: This is hardly necessary - all that's need is to remove the 2 attributes from the method.

Comment: It transfoms your 'a' tag into 'submit' button. And it posts your log out request to controller with an AntiForgeryToken. After that your controller checks your AntiForgeryToken because your LogOff function has '[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]' tag.

Comment: If you want to add a css class to your log off button, you can add a class to your link. Like: <a class="YourButtonClass" href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">